# Windows Store App - Dynamic Data Binding

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding

I want to update dinamically the value of a ProgressBar defined in my XAML:

```
<ProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                 Height="90" Margin="0,-30,0,0" 
                 VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                 Width="600" x:Name="BarProgress" Value="{Binding Test}" Maximum="100" />
```

In the Control of the page i have defined this class:

```
public class TestData
{
    public double Test { get; set; }
}
```

And in the LoadState method:

```
TestData data = new TestData();
data.Test = downloadData.ProgressValue();
BarProgress.DataContext = data;
```

Finally in the class that is responsible for download the file i have the ProgressValue function that return the percentace of download.
The binding seems to work but it's not dynamic...I can see in the ProgressBar only the first value i've set for downloadData.ProgressValue()...
Which is the right way for a dynamic binding?!?!

Comment: Usually when you see the first value but no changes then you've forgotten to notify on property change so the data binding never updates. Check out [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: The class responsible for download, that return the value downloadData.ProgressValue(), extends INotifyPropertyChanged...

Answer (score 0):

Your property `Test` doesn't notify, it just uses the automatically generated backing fields.

You are also assigning the value type return from a function (`ProgressValue()`) to that property rather than an object. This means that at no stage is a property change notification happening, so the databinding never knows that the value has changed.

You need to extend your `TestData` class:

```
public class TestData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public double Test 
    { 
        get { return _test; } 
        set 
        { 
            _test = value;  
            OnPropertyChange("Test");
        }
    }

    private double _test;

    private void OnPropertyChange(string propertyName)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChanged;
}
```

*(typed entirely from memory, not copy pasted from editor, excuse any typos)*

and you also need to either regularly update the value (by repeatedly calling `ProgressValue()`) or you need to work out a different way to put the updated value into that property.

Comment: OK, really interesting...how can i update with continuity the value of the variable?as you can see i call the ProgressValue function one time in the LoadState...maybe another idea could be declaring a public variable in the MainPage.xaml.cs and the invoking it from the download Class?

Comment: probably also the LoadState method is not the right place for the code...but where?!?